# Frame Not Drawn on Customized Window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, frame, custom-component

I have a customized window which implements corporate design guideline from my company.

I have to load HTML in Frame object in WPF. The problem is that when I place Frame with source html path in WPF using CustomizedWindow, Frame does not get drawn (only background color of frame is visible, not any data on the source)

And If I use normal Window (Not CustomizedWindow), the Frame is drawn properly with HTML content. Is there something, that I need to override for Frame drawing to work properly in my CustomizedWindow.

Please let me know if you need any further information on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a problem.
I commented AllowsTransparency Property on Window Styles and every thing works fine. I have lost some functionality provided by this property, but I am still fine with it. 
If anybody have better solutions, please post it here.